# VBA: proper date format to use

Tags: excel, vba

I have few cells where I fill date,and later I use these for calculations(substractions),so tell me which date format is good to use here. That should work for all regional languages and for all date separations like "-","/",".".Example - 12.1.2013.

I tried with - 
//Format and Formatdatetime functions

Suggest me some answers please.
Thanks.

Comment: The number formatting of a cell does not interfere with later calculations, unless you use it's value as a text

Comment: Cells in what? Excel? If so they should be dates, but displayed in a format. Which format should be irrelevant.

Comment: I`m using those cells in formulas'.like "Ax1-Ax2+1".So it`ll affect when ax1 and ax2 are different formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For universal dates I'd recommend one of three in order of my preference:

1. `01-FEB-2013`, as a format `dd-mmm-yyyy`
2. `20130201`, as format `yyyymmdd`
3. `01022013`, as a format `ddmmyyyy`

Comment: glh: Thanks for the answer. formats should be set in vba or excel(format cell)???